# Read a story about bad news

Tags: hadith, death

I heave just read a story called "wasiyat nama(A will)" that talked about a sheikh, who said that the Holy Prophet (P.B.U.H) has come in his dream, and told him that the world has forgotten the teachings of Islam, and now you have to tell them to come on the right way.
At the end, there's a message which is saying that the reader should get this story copied 100 times and distributed. And it also says that a man in Bangladesh didn't do that and his son died. But on the other hand, a man got it copied and he got profit in his business.

**PLEASE** tell me whether it is true or not, and will anything bad happen to me if I don't get this story copied and distributed? Note that I can't afford to get it copied or anything else...

Comment: It is wrong and the one who has sent this is Kaffir. The one who says a lie by mentioned our Prophet Hazrat Muhammad (P.B.U.H) name is Kuffur.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things like this in every country. But please mention that happening bad things and good things to someone is related to our thoughts. If you think that if you do not copy this you will suffer anything bad, so you will suffer bad things. But if you do not care to this and you sure that it wouldn't hurt you, so it would not hurt you.

But for clarifying this, I have to say something:

> All of these stories are lies. Specifically for this story, how can
>   the world forget the Islam orders as we have Qur'an in our hands? This
>   is true that many Muslims do what they want and omit the Qur'an orders
>   in their lives, But it is not public.

And it is Satan behind this copying and distributing. Satan wants to divert your attention from the real order to false ones.